# Workflow for editing list items

Tags: list, workflow

SP 2013

I have two lists TestList and Test2. I have successfully set a workflow up that copies a couple of fields of data from TestList to Test2 when a new record is created.

I now want to allow the user to be able to edit the record in Test 1 and the change to be reflected in the same record in test2. I have tried to set up another workflow.

IF CurrentItem:Name is not empty
Update Item in Test2

Also set up the following

[image]

In the Start Options - I have the following ticked only

Start Workflow Automatically when an item is changed

I get an error when running.

Probably gone completely wrong with this - any help appreciated.

Comment: Please post the error you are getting while workflow is running.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, You are following same approach which I tested and its working for me.

1. Enable workflow on created and modified.
2. Update listItem of Test2 list using **Update List Item** action.

can you log error and on which line error is occurring and post here as screenshot?